# hide a div when clicking outside 2 div jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem with js

i have a icon and a form
my form is appear when i click on icon

i want to my form was hide when clicked outside form
now when i click on icon to show my form , js hide my form becuase it outside of my form
any body can help me?

mycode for show/hide when click on icon:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#icon").click(function(){
        $("#form-subscribe").animate({
            height: 'toggle'
        });
    });
});
```

and my code for hide form when clicked outside of form:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#main").mouseup(function(e)
    {
        var subject = $("#form-subscribe");

        if(e.target.id != subject.attr('id') && !subject.has(e.target).length)
        {
            $("#form-subscribe").animate({
            height: 'hide'
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Provide html code.

Comment: you can see my form on site:
https://khorshied.com

person icon

Comment: Can you add a snippet or a jsfiddle link for your code

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by inspecting the `e.target` DOM node inside of a jQuery `$.contains()` method.

Link to jQuery Contains Method: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.contains/

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/eq43eve5/

HTML:

```
<div>
  <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>

<form id="form">
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input>
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.fa').on('click', function() {
  $('#form').show();
})

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
  // If e.target is not inside of the form container AND not
  // the icon triggering the initial showing of the form,
  // hide the form div.
  if (!$.contains(document.querySelector('#form'), e.target) && !$(e.target).hasClass('fa')) {
    $('#form').hide();
  }
})
```